# Easiest Way to Transform a Wide String or Wide Character Array to a Simple Character Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, widestring, character-arrays

My variable is in a specific internal implementation of a wide string but I can get it to be a wide character array quite easily. The problem is I need to feed it to a library function that will only accept character arrays.

So I end up with what looks like this:

```
wchar_t* wstr;

// char* str = "need some processing here";

function(str);
```

So, is there an easy way or should I just do it manually character by character?

Comment: It depends a bit of what you are trying to do with the result and what the original contains. If you just want to process ASCII characters, you'd want `std::ctype<whar_t>::narrow()`. If the function expects a muti-byte encoding something like `wcstombs()` is needed. Note, that the latter are typically not considered characters but a sequence of byte.

Comment: This seems to be working for me although I found a better solution to my problem that doesn't require this conversion. But thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

char* can mean a lot of things. If the function taking the char* is actually taking UTF8, there are ways to transform UTF16 or UTF32 to UTF8. wchar_t is commonly used to store UTF16 (windows) or UTF32 (macosx), amongst other enencodings.

Have a look here for ConvertUTF.c/.h

[unicode.org code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MJEVANS/DBD-ODBC-1.39/)

Comment: How can I know if it takes UTF-8 or not?

Comment: Simply put, UTF8 is one of many ways to encode a char array to represent most characters/letters/symbols/etc... of most languages. It is probably the most popular. If you are calling into a function defined by some library, check the documentation to see what kind of char* it expects. Many popular APIs expect a char* to be UTF8. If you know that your wchar_t input will only ever be English characters (ascii codes 32 to 127), then you can transform the wchar_t to char* using the above mentioned library because those characters are valid in all char* encoding schemes.